# Error when using Operation not supported using firmadyne

Tags: firmware-analysis

I'm using firmware-analysis-toolkits, and as part of the toolkit, it uses firmadyne. When trying to emulate a TP-LINK firmware, I'm encountering this error.

```
swRegWrite: Operation not supported
swRegRead: Operation not supported
```